# How to update tar (NOT append)

Tags: linux, bash, compression, tar

I want to update an existing tar file with ***newer*** files.

At GNU, I read:

> 4.2.3 Updating an Archive
>
> In the previous section, you learned how to use ‘--append’ to add a
>   file to an existing archive. A related operation is ‘--update’ (‘-u’).
>   **The ‘--update’ operation updates a tar archive by comparing the date
>   of the specified archive members against the date of the file with the
>   same name. If the file has been modified more recently than the
>   archive member, then the newer version of the file is added to the
>   archive (as with ‘--append’)**.

However,
When I run my tar update command, the files are appended even though their modification dates are exactly the same. I want to ONLY append where modification dates of files to be tarred are newer than those already in the tar...

```
tar -uf ./tarfile.tar /localdirectory/ >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Currently, every time I update, the tar doubles in size...

Comment: Is it perhaps because I am omitting the flag to preserve beginning slashes ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Add `-P` flag to make it work. Or you can use `cd /; tar -uf /path/file.tar localdirectory` (for some strange reason `tar -uf file.tar -C / localdirectory` does not working for sequential calls with my tar version).

Comment: It is impossible: `tar` means originally *tape archive* and you cannot replace a file in the middle of a magnetic tape.

Comment: Perhaps tardy (a tar post-processor) could interest you http://tardy.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning! When speaking about "dates" it means *any* date, and that includes the access time.

Should your files have been accessed in any such way (a simple `ls -l` is enough) then tar is right to do what it does!

You need to find another way to do what you want. Probably use a sentinel file and see if its modification date is less than the files you wish to append.

Comment: Ok, what you are saying makes sense. Sorry for my earlier confusion. So, I guess tar operates on access date rather than modification date? That seems silly since tar will access the files every time I run tar -u...lol

Comment: You have three dates to a file: the access time (atime), the inode modification time (ctime) and the content modification time (mtime). If any of these change, then the "date" of the file changes.

Comment: Addendum: there are operations which *do not* affect atime, and one example is `stat()`, or `lstat()`. This is probably what tar uses for `-u`.

Answer (score 3):

The update you describe implies that the file within the archive is *replaced*. If the new copy is smaller than what's in the archive, it could be directly rewritten. If the new copy however is larger, tar would have to zero the existing archive entry and append. Such updates would leave runs of '\0's or other unused bytes, so any normal computer user would want that such sections are removed, which would be done by "moving up" bytes comprising the archive contents towards the start of the file (think C's memmove).

Such an in-place move operation however, which would involve seek-read-seek-write cycles, is *costly*, especially when you look at it in the context of tapes — which tar was designed for originally —, i.e. devices with a seek performance that is not comparable to harddisks. You'd wear out the tape rather quickly with such move ops. Oh and of course, WORM devices don't support this move op either.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use the `-P` switch `tar -u...` works correctly if the current directory is the **parent** directory of the one we are going to update, and the path to this directory in the `tar` command will **not** be an absolute path.
For example:
We want to update catalog /home/blabla/Dir. We do it like that:

```bash
cd /home/blabla  
tar -u -f tarfile.tar Dir
```

In general, the update must be made from the same place as the creation, so that the paths agree.
It is also possible:

```bash
cd /home/blabla/Dir
tar -u -f /path/to/tarfile.tar .
```

Answer (score 1):

You may simply create (instead of update) the archive each time:

`tar -cvpf tarfile.tar *`

This will solve the problem of your archive doubling in size each time. But of course, it is generating the whole archive every time.

Answer (score 1):

By default tar strips the leading `/` from member names, but it does this after deciding what needs to be updated.

Therefore if you are archiving an absolute path, you either need to `cd /` and use relative paths, or add the `-P/--absolute-names` option.

```sh
cd /
tar -uf "$OLDPWD/tarfile.tar" localdirectory/ >/dev/null 2>&1
```

```sh
tar -cPf tarfile.tar /localdirectory/ >/dev/null 2>&1
tar -uPf tarfile.tar /localdirectory/ >/dev/null 2>&1
```

However, the updated items will still be appended. A `tar` (`t`ape `ar`chive) file cannot be modified excpet by appending.

Comment: Somehow in 8 years nobody put the actual answer in an answer.